# Select2, when no option matches, "other" should appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

With select2 dropdown, how do I get a default option to appear if no options match the user's typed input?

```
$("something").select2({
  formatNoMatches: function(term) {
    //return a search choice
  }
});
```

I haven't been able to find anything that really matches this desired functionality within the select2 documentation or Stack Overflow.

**Edit**
I'm getting closer with this

```
$("something").select2({
  formatNoMatches: function(term) {
    return "<div class='select2-result-label'><span class='select2-match'></span>Other</div>"
  }
});
```

But this is pretty hacky off the bat, and also isn't clickable.

Comment: Not too familiar with `select2`, but this posting might help: https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/issues/448

Comment: Are you using it attached to a `select` or `hidden` input?

Comment: Reading last documentation (I used an old version) I see there's a way to do it with a function, but indicating the action after an underscore, it could be $("something_get") for example. I only had to use basic matching.

Comment: @MaximilianoRios Can you elaborate, or point me to the documentation you're viewing?

Comment: Of course, find it here: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Comment: Come on -- I've looked at the select2 documentation ;). I meant "can you point me to the documentation that references `$("something_get")`"?

Comment: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#documentation. Look for Programmatic Access, there're examples for _get and _set. I think it's not necessary to vote me down, just point if I'm wrong to help everybody

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To complement on @vararis's answer:

Select2 attached to a `<select>` element does not allow for custom `createSearchChoice` nor `query` functions, hence we will need to manually add an option element (I'll add it as the last option of the element so we can easily [`.pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) it out of the results set):

```
<select>
  ...
  <option value="0">Other</option>
</select>
```

Then pass a custom `matcher` function so that this "Other" option is always matched.

**NOTE:** Select2 3.4+ uses a [different default matcher](https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/blob/2ab64be416241183b39d43b0a549302d0875556e/select2.js#L3161-L3163) than the one currently shown in the documentation, this new one has a call to the `stripDiacritics` function so that `a` matches `á` for instance. Therefore I'll apply the default `matcher` that comes with the Select2 version included in the page to apply its default matching algorithm to any option that's not the "Other" option:

```
matcher: function(term, text) {
  return text==='Other' || $.fn.select2.defaults.matcher.apply(this, arguments);
},
```

Finally, we need to remove the "Other" option from the results set when there's any result besides the "Other" result (which is initially always in the results set):

```
sortResults: function(results) {
  if (results.length > 1) results.pop();
  return results;
}
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FNwMN/)

Comment: Note that I don't think the second part of this will work if 'other' is not at the end of the result set (like ['apples', 'other', 'trees'], but it's pretty obvious how to precede from here.

Comment: Yeah, I commented that part on the beginning. `=]` Even if you have some kind of sorting, I'd append the `Other` option afterwards for conveniently `.pop()`ing it out. But it is not hard to iterate over the result set array and `.splice()` the `Other` result out either.

Comment: The matcher signature changed for Select2 version 4+, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55281227/729324

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by changing the matcher.

```
$('#activity_log_industry_name').select2
  matcher: (term, text) ->
    if text=="Other"
      return true
    text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase())>=0
```

(this is in coffeescript.) The only problem is that "Other" will pop up for any search -- but this can be easily solved by modifying the `sortResults` function.

Answer (score 1):

In version 4+ of Select2, the matcher should be passed like this:

```js
$("something").select2({
    matcher: function(params, data) {
        if (data.id === "0") { // <-- option value of "Other", always appears in results
            return data;
        } else {
            return $.fn.select2.defaults.defaults.matcher.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    },
});
```

the "Other" option should be appended to the option list like this:

```
<select>
  ...
  <option value="0">Other</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

To customize formatNoMatches use following code in your view

`ui-select2="{formatNoMatches:'No Results Found'}"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18722148/select2-jquery-not-allow-to-add-new-tags)

```
createSearchChoice: function (term) {
  return { id: term, text: term };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to display the message as 'Other' when no matches found

```
$("select").select2({ 
formatNoMatches   :    function(term) {       
    return   "Other";
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try it, this work in newer version ( Select2 4.0.3 )
without add a new variable.

**[>>>> Fiddle here <<<<](http://jsfiddle.net/kinggeneral/gt8j1d82/)**

first you need to download javascript name "**[github/alasql](https://github.com/agershun/alasql)**"
to search like query in data

```
<select id="something">
  ...
  <option value="other">Other</option> <!-- or put this in "dataItemsList" for dynamic option -->
</select>
```

then in your javascript

```
// other than this array we will give "other" option
var ajax_search_array = ['your', 'item', 'for', 'search'];

$("#something").select2({
   placeholder: "Choose your something",
   //data: dataItemsList, //your dataItemsList for dynamic option
   //...
   //...
   tags: true,
   createTag: function (tag) {
        // here we add %search% to search like in mysql
        var name_search  = "%"+tag.term.toString().toLowerCase()+"%";

        // alasql search
        var result = alasql('SELECT COLUMN * FROM [?] WHERE [0] LIKE ?',[ajax_search_array, name_search]);

        // if no result found then show "other"
        // and prevent other to appear when type "other"
        if(result==false && tag.term != "other"){
            return {
               id: "other",
               text: "Other"
            };
        }
});
```

hope this work.

Comment: HI .. i just need to add other option when there is not matching element in result. can you please help me

Comment: @DhrumilShah here we go, check the link there, i have updates my fiddle. i have used javascript name alasql.

Comment: Thanks a lot @KingGeneral.. But i am having "Other" as one option. when i am typing other there are two result is matching. i just need one result. Can you please suggest

Comment: did you mean when typing other , it displaying 2 other ?? ah already fixed that, see the code above / fiddle

Comment: Hi @KingGeneral. its still visible two other option. i think below code is not comparing other value. Please help... if(result==false && tag.term != "other"){
            return {
               id: "other",
               text: "Other"
            };
        }

Comment: can you give me your fiddle here.

Comment: Hi @kingGeneral.. I am referring to your fiddle only http://jsfiddle.net/kinggeneral/gt8j1d82/

Comment: Hi @KingGeneral.. After adding below code its working as i want.. Thanks for your help..  
// other than this array we will give "other" option
var ajax_search_array = ['other','zone', 'kg', 'windows', 'uac'];