# select2 jquery not allow to add new tags

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have this code and I do not allow to add new tags just picks those from the ajax .

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
     url: "ajax/profile.php",
     type: "POST", 
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data) {
         //alert(data);
         $("#PROFILE").select2({
             tags: data,
             tokenSeparators: [","]
 }); 
         }, error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
         {
             alert("Ocurrio un error al enviar los datos");
         }
     });

});
</script>
```

appreciate your help

Answer (score 10):

Add the below code inside the `select2()` function. Check [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XQ8Fw/)

```
createSearchChoice: function (term) {
  return { id: term, text: term };
}
```