# Using a list of string elements as source for Select2 component

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-select2

I'm trying to work out a tag controller for this website I'm working on, but I can't get the json-part to work properly.

To start from the top, I have a hidden input element in my cshtml-view (JS fetched from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18722148/select2-jquery-not-allow-to-add-new-tags)):

```
<input type="hidden" id="tagController" style="width: 350px;" />
...
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var lastResults = [];

        $("#tagController").select2({
            multiple: true,
            placeholder: "Please enter tags",
            tokenSeparators: [","],
            ajax: {
                multiple: true,
                url: "/UnitDetails/GetTagsAsJson/",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                data: function (term, page) {
                    return {
                        json: JSON.stringify({ results: [{ id: "foo", text: "foo" }, { id: "bar", text: "bar" }] }),
                        q: term
                    };
                },
                results: function (data, page) {
                    lastResults = data.results;
                    return data;
                }
            },
            createSearchChoice: function (term) {
                var text = term + (lastResults.some(function (r) { return r.text == term }) ? "" : " (new)");
                return { id: term, text: text };
            },
        });
    });
```

Then, I have an action in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetTagsAsJson()
{
    return Json(Model.TagsAvailable, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then, the list `TagsAvailable` is populated in my index action:

```
...
foreach (var tag in GetAvailableTags())
{
    Model.TagsAvailable.Add(tag.Name);
}
...
```

Finally, the `GetAvailableTags()` is calling a wcf service which returns a set of TagContracts in a `BaseTagController`:

```
public List<TagContract> GetAvailableTags()
{
    return UnitClient.GetAllUnitTags().Select(unitTag => new TagContract
                                                             {
                                                                 Id = unitTag.Id,
                                                                 Name = unitTag.Name
                                                             }).ToList();
}
```

When inspecting the console in chrome, I get the following error:
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

For the record, I know for a fact that the service returns the requested data, it's more a problem with the code I've written I guess :)

Comment: Aren't you posting to an action with data, but your method signature for that action takes no parameters. I don't think GetTagsAsJson() is getting hit, it's trying to call GetTagsAsJson(results)

Comment: You should try to debug your GetTagsAsJson action and see when it brokes. Moreover, why using HttpPost and returning a json allowed in GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came across a tutorial which helped me accomplish what I wanted. Simply just rewrote the code to match my values.

Github code can be found [here](https://github.com/thuventhiran/Select2Example).